# Camera Rotation value on y axis get high float number by time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

i try to create free look camera i was follow tutorial on YouTube everything work fine except i noticed that the rotation value about the y axis which is stored in float variable the angle value is getting Continue to accumulate i try to clamp it but its result in undesired behavior i also try the mathf.repeat the same i tried to zero the angle if it larger than 360 but this create another instant rotation in the opposite dir , i use the += operator which i think it causes this if I am not mistaken

my question dose this affect the performance i target mobile device's in general

If it affects performance, how should I deal with this problem?

thank you for any help really

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;


public class Camera : MonoBehaviour



{

    public Transform target;

    public float destotarget;

    public float sensetivity;

    public float smoothTime;

    public float yaw;

    public float pitch;

    public Vector2 minandmax = new Vector2(34, 54);

    public Vector3 currnetrot;

    public Vector3 velocitysmooth;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        yaw += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensetivity;
        pitch += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensetivity;

        pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, minandmax.x, minandmax.y);

        currnetrot = Vector3.SmoothDamp(currnetrot, new Vector2(pitch, yaw), ref velocitysmooth, smoothTime);
        transform.eulerAngles = currnetrot;

        transform.position = target.position - transform.forward * destotarget;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This shouldn't effect the performance much, but the only way to ever know is to profile:**

1. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/profiler-profiling-applications.html
2. https://blog.theknightsofunity.com/mobile-optimization-unity-profiler/